# How to make 'other' text field in drop-down menu required?

Tags: html, css

How do you make the 'other' text field in a drop-down menu required to be filled? I currently have a drop down-menu that has a 'required' attribute, but the user is able to proceed without filling in the text in the text field. Selecting the 'Other' option alone goes thru.

Is is there a solution that involves HTML and CSS?

And what about adding minimum character length like this `pattern=".{3,}"` attribute?

Comment: If you mean you have a select and a text input, and the input is required if and only if the select says "Other", then no, that can't be done in static HTML and CSS. Use JavaScript.

Comment: No. I did write that the whole Drop-down menu itself has a 'required' attribute.